# Querying H2 using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple class:

```
class Song {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
private long id;
private String composition;
private String performer;
private String version;
private int length; //  Length in seconds
private int rating; //  Rating

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Source> sources;
...
}
```

I persist some records to the H2 database.
I can grab the list of all records without a problem (can get count as well), but when I do a query with "where" clause I always get empty list.
This are the queries I have tried:

```
List<Song> result = (List<Song>) entityManager.createQuery("FROM Song WHERE performer = "artist").getResultList();
```

I tried following versions of the query without any luck:

```
"SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.performer = 'artist'"
"FROM Song WHERE str(performer) like 'artist'"
```

This problem is driving me crazy. I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Have you tried "Select s FROM Song s where s.performer = :artist" Then, query.setParameter("artist","artist")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its case sensitive, are you sure db has 'artist' as value with no trailing space or anything ?

Comment: I am pretty sure DB table has "performer" field. I verified that by looking at the Hibernate "insert" queries.

Comment: that is fine . but does it contain a value = 'artist'. it has to be exactly this value.

Comment: I am certain it does contain 'artist'.

Comment: what query does hibernte generate for this? you can copy the same query and paste in db and put the value 'artist' instead of '?' and see what results do you get

Comment: Turns out the order of parameters was switched when I was persisting them. I did not notice that when printing all entries.